# Appending Last row series of a dataframe to another dataframe nested within dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd 
d1 = {  }
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "A": ["A0", "A1", "A2", "A3"],
        "B": ["B0", "B1", "B2", "B3"],
        "C": ["C0", "C1", "C2", "C3"],
        "D": ["D0", "D1", "D2", "D3"],
    },
    index=[0, 1, 2, 3])

for i in range(1, len(df1)):
    d1[i].append(df1.tail(1))
    print(d1[i])
```

> d1 is dictionary of dataframes. I expect the 4 dataframes to be filled
> in with last row from df1 dataframe.
>
> I get following error :
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:/Users/xxxx/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2021.2/scratches/Pandas
> and Dictionary.py", line 14, in 
> d1[i].append(df1.tail(1)) KeyError: 1

Answer (score 2):

Your

```
KeyError: 1
```

is caused by

```
d1[i].append(...)
```

in your second last line. If you want to add a new dict entry, you can just do

```
d1[key] = value
```

I don't know if this answers your question wholly.

**Update:**

I would suggest initializing d1 as a pd.DataFrame as well.
Then you can fetch the last row of df1 and append it onto d1.

```
d1 = pd.DataFrame(colums=["A", "B", "C", "D"])
last_row = df1[-1:]
d1 = pd.concat([d1, last_row])
```

This snippet will append your last row to your global DF, assuming they have matching column names.

Comment: Moe thanks. Please see my comment to Cimbali and suggest please.

Comment: With last row you mean the actual row of the DataFrame I assume? In your example, this would be ["A3", "B3", "C3", "D3"]. If you want to select this last row, you can use: df1[-1:]
This selects every row from the last (-1) to everything after.

Comment: Yes. The last of the df1 shall revise after certain time elapse since df1 is a time series dataframe. I need to keep appending this row in the d1 dictionary for all dataframes in it.

Comment: Can you maybe eleborate a bit more what you want to achive with your program as a whole? Maybe we can give you better answeres this way.

Comment: Yes sure ... I have a function which is receiving streaming data every seconds in dataframe df1. This dataframe has comprehensive data for '0' '1', '2', and '3' items. I am resampling this data. I then need to add this data to a global defined dictionnary d1 which is collections of dataframes (essentially 4 data frames '0','1',  '2', '3'). However during this activity I need to only extract last row from df1 and amend to each dataframe. Essentially building up the global dataframe for further processing. I hope this is clearer. If not let me know.

Comment: I updated my answer, please take a look at it.

Comment: Yes but I need to have a dictionary of dataframes within those. How to initialise those ? The number of dataframes within the dictionary have to be scalable in terms of numbers so in the above example its 4 dataframes but that could be 6, 8 or any number..

Comment: I don&#39;t quite understand yet why you need to save them in a dict? Cant you just use the indices of the DataFrame to get the entries you need?

But appending a DataFrame to your dict can be done like so:

    d1[key] = last_row

Answer (score 2):

Let’s decompose what `df1[i].append(…)` does:

- `df1[i]` is taking the value in `df1` that has the key `i`
- `.append(…)` is then calling the append function on this value, as if it were e.g. a list

However your dictionary is empty. What you want instead is:

```
for i in range(1, len(df1)):
    d1[i] = df1.tail(1)
```

See also the `d[key]` and `d[key] = value` entries of [the python dict documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/stdtypes.html#dict).

Comment: Many thanks. I agree with your answer. My apologies I perhaps did not explain it properly. The df1 is a dynamic timeseries dataframe and I need to extract last row and fill in the empty dictionary of of dataframes successively and hence the append function. thus populating the dataframes in d1